# Android Drag Sprite code Unity 5

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm new to Unity and have been following a tutorial on how to make a Captain Blaster 2D game, however I want to convert it to Android, I want to make the player controllable by dragging him across the screen with one finger and don't understand what's wrong with my code, anything helps, thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ShipControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public float playerSpeed = 10f;
    public GameControl gameController;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float reloadTime = 1f;

    private float elapsedTime = 0;


    void Update()
    {

        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) 
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100)) {

                }
            }

        if (elapsedTime > reloadTime)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position;
            spawnPos += new Vector3 (0, 1.2f, 0);
            Instantiate (bulletPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

                elapsedTime = 0f;
        }
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        gameController.PlayerDied ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the section of code that determines that the finger was, in fact, touching something is empty...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is add a bool called "dragging" and after you check if Raycast hit anything you also check if hit object is the player GameObject.
If it is then as long as user is not releasing the touch - make player's rigidbody move towards the touch position (so if there are any obstacles it simply doesn't move right through them).

Code would probably look like this (you should also add some timer to check if player released touch and set dragging bool to false):

```
public float playerSpeed = 10f;
public GameControl gameController;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float reloadTime = 1f;

private float elapsedTime = 0;

private bool dragging = false;


void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) 
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100)) 
            {
                if(hit.collider.tag == "Player") // check if hit collider has Player tag
                {
                    dragging = true;
                }
            }

            if(dragging)
            {
                //First rotate the player towards the touch (should do some checks if it's not too close so it doesn't glitch out)
                Vector3 _dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) - transform.position;
                _dir.Normalize();

                float _rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(_dir.y, _dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, _rotZ - 90);

                //Move towards the touch
                transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(direction.normalized * playerSpeed, ForceMode.Force);
            }
        }
    }
}
```